# Show if tableview cell have been clicked before?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, parse-platform

I'm developing an app with a news feed.

This is a `PFQueryTableView` loading content from parse.com.

I also have a detail `ViewController` attached with a segue.

My question is:

**How can I show that there is a cell that hasn't been clicked before?**

Like in the Mail application in IOS.

Here's a picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vO2N3.png

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Nyhet";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"Rubrik";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 10;
}
return self;
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
return UIStatusBarStyleDefault;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Change button color
sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

// Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);


// Set the gesture
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
/*    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
}*/

[query orderByDescending:@"Prioritering"];

return query;
}



// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Rubrik"];

UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
prepTimeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Detaljer"];



return cell;
}

- (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];
    recipe.name = [object objectForKey:@"Rubrik"];
    recipe.prepTime = [object objectForKey:@"Text"];
    recipe.detaljer = [object objectForKey:@"Detaljer"];
    recipe.rubriker = [object objectForKey:@"Rubrik"];
    destViewController.recipe = recipe;

}
}


@end
```

Comment: Why not simply use an array to hold the `indexPath.row` of all the visited cells? Use `NSNumber`s. I don't really know what kind of data you are using to plot your cells. If they are a `mutableDictionary`, simply use a key for this.

Comment: Kind of new to IOS programming so if you could give an example that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better use custom UITableViewCell example:

```
CustomTableViewCell.h
```

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(assign) bool beforeClicked

@end
```

```
CustomTableViewCell.m
```

```
#import CustomTableViewCell.h

@implementation CustomTableViewCell
@synthesize beforeClicked;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And, example:

```
CustomTableViewCell.h //add this header
```

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Rubrik"];

    UILabel *prepTimeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    prepTimeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Detaljer"];

    cell.beforeClicked = NO;

    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    myCell.beforeClicked = YES;
}
```

Comment: a cell alone doesnt help at all because it can be reused. cells are not meant to keep 'state'

Comment: Yes. it's better while not reload data of table.

Comment: yes I agree there. I'd also use a custom cell for display BUT in combination with remembering state in the Model object

Comment: the way you remember state in cells doesnt work even if you never reload

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions come to mind.

- The simpler solution would be using an `NSMutableArray` to hold all visited cells. In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` do this :

  ```
  if (![visitedCellsArray containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]])
      [visitedCellsArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
  ```

Then set a `backgroundColor` to your cell (just a suggestion, you may use any UI indicator - dot, color, etc) in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

- Second, might not be conducive to your purpose. I don't really know if the dictionary you are using is mutable or not, and whether adding keys will have any effect on your flow of control. But If adding a key is possible, add a key like @"seen" and set it with `[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` add appropriate UI indication based on the value of this key. This method is better memory wise.

Comment: That sounds good im thinking of using a bolder font for the "unread" news do you think that would be possible or should i go with something like a dot?

Comment: this might work but is a hack and wont scale.. also it isnt very elegant. I would just give my Model objects a property 'Unread' .. that way the state is even persisted

Answer (score 0):

I'd give your PFReceipt objects a property BOOL new.

Then just get and set that property and in cellForRow you set the font based on the vale of the property.

clean and even persistent.

...

so to reiterate:

1. modify PFReceipt object to have a property new
2. modify `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object`

   ```
   ...
   cell.clickedBefore = !receipe.new;
   ```
3. mark receipes as no longer new when shown

   ```
   ...
   - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
      if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
          ...
          PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
          selectedCell.clickedBefore = !object.new;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions provided take into account that there may be more than one user of the app. If you store a "read" or "new" property in the object, this will only show if ANYBODY has read it. So if Jane reads it, Mark will see it as read.

To handle this separately for all users, you need another parse class to handle reading status. This gets a little complex to implement, but it is the only way to solve it all on the server.

Another option would be to store a read status list on every client. This means some kind of local persistent store that knows what recipes are read, and compare this to the data fetched from Parse.